# How to select td tags with Regular Expressions?

Tags: html, regex

I try to select `td` tags with **Regular Expressions**  via Visual Studio search and replace. I use `<td (?s).*) >` regular  expression but it doesn't work.

Sample HTML:

```
<td style="width: 54pt; border-style: none solid solid; border-right-color: windowtext; border-bottom-color: windowtext; border-left-color: windowtext; border-right-width: 1pt; border-bottom-width: 1pt; border-left-width: 1pt; padding: 0cm 5.4pt; height: 14.25pt;" nowrap="" valign="top" width="72">
```

Please advise.

Comment: Just `<td [^>]*>` should be enough. Or w/out attributes: `<td(?: [^>]*)?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this simple regex:

```
<td [^>]*>
```

If the attributes are optional, use

```
<td(?: [^>]*)?>
```

The `<td [^>]*>` matches `<td` followed with a space and zero or more characters other than `>` up to the first `>`. The `(?:...)?` is an optional non-capturing group that makes matching the text in-between `<td` and `>` optional.

If a `>` can appear as literal inside your `<td>` nodes, use `[^<]*?` instead of `[^>]*`.

And one more caveat: if the `<td` appears one 1 line, and the rest is on the next (or more) lines, use `[\s\r]+` instead of the literal space:

```
<td(?:[\s\r]+[^>]*)?>
```

The fact is that VS search and replace regex does not match a carriage return with `\s`.